# Angular application crashes when getting data rapidly using websockets

Tags: node.js, angular

I am getting data from websocket nodejs backend pretty rapidly and i am showing on the frontend using *ngFor and after some time my application start lagging and eventually crash after some time. Looking for the solution.

I am looking if async can help me show changing data with *ngFor

**rates.component.html**

```
<ul>
    <li (click)="coin(coinz.type)" *ngFor="let coinz of btcCoins">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span>
           {{coinz.symbol}}/ BTC
        </span>
        <span class="float-right">
            {{coinz.percent | number:'1.1-2'}}
            {{coinz.price}}
        </span>
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**rates.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit()
{
   this.socketService.getPrice().subscribe(data =>
   {
      this.btcCoins= data;
   });
}
```

**socket.service.ts**

```
bidask()
{
   let observable = new Observable(observer =>
   {
       this.socket = io(this.domain);
       this.socket.on('bidasks', (data) =>
       {
          observer.next(data);
       });
       return () =>
       {
          this.socket.disconnect();
       };
   });
   return observable;
}
```

Comment: What is showing in the console, are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors in console everything going fine **but data changing so rapidly** that it cause the browser to crash.

Comment: I think you need to use NgZone for change detection and that should be done outside of Angular

Comment: By "Crash" do you mean the browser/UI becomes unresponsive? Sounds like you may exceeding the browser limitations by making too many changes to quickly. I'm not sure how you're displaying you data, but you may consider 'paging' or slowing your updates down from "realtime" to say every second, 5 seconds, or whatever is acceptable for you use case.

Comment: By crash i mean browser start lagging

Answer (score 1):

When iterating over a large and partially changing collection, make sure you use `trackBy`.

A very straight-forward tutorial can be found at https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5

Answer (score 0):

You could trying using the delay() operator on the Observable to slow down the rate of data being fed to the component - what may be happening is that the component is in a constant state of refresh, and eventually is overwhelmed.

```
bidask()
{
   let observable = new Observable(observer =>
   {
       this.socket = io(this.domain);
       this.socket.on('bidasks', (data) =>
       {
          observer.next(data);
       });
       return () =>
       {
          this.socket.disconnect();
       };
   });
   return observable.delay(100);
}
```

Where `return observable` **.delay(100)** is the change, and **100** is the ms delay.